# API.ai Issue in connecting with local server

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I was new to API.ai and I created a sample application for that I am using my own local web service which will be running on my local machine with the URL "http://0.0.0.0:5000/webhook" I have enabled and added the URL in the fulfilments and in the indents under the fulfilment tab I checked the use webhook but while I was trying to run the project the post action does not take place.
   and the web service does not trigger from my sample API ai application and in the JSON I get the status as

"status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty."
  },

What should i need to do?

Kindly assist me regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't fill in your localhost, API.ai has no idea how to reach that from their side. It's only accessible on your own machine.

You would need something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). ngrok will expose your localhost to the internet making it accessible from outside sources like API.ai for example.

Simple download the ngrok zip file and open up the terminal/command line. Depending on your OS you could run ngrok with:

```
ngrok http 5000
```

After that simply copy/paste the https url that ngrok exposes for you and put it as url in the fulfillment page on API.ai.